# Set cursor position when creating a state from a string with Draft.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, draftjs

How can I set the cursor position after creating an EditorState with content and some decorators on [Draft.js](https://draftjs.org/). It always starts on the position 0.

This is what happens:

[image]

This is what I want:

[image]

Here is how I am creating the state.

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { editorState: this.getEditorState() }
  }

  getEditorState() {
    const { reply: { channel, userAccount } } = this.props
    const content = this.getEditorContent({ channel, userAccount })
    const decorators = this.getEditorDecorators(channel)
    return EditorState.createWithContent(content, decorators)
  }

  getEditorContent({ channel, userAccount }) {
    const content = channel && channel.prefill(userAccount)
    return ContentState.createFromText(content || '')
  }

  getEditorDecorators({ decorators }) {
    return getDecorators(decorators || [])
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading the [issue 224](https://github.com/facebook/draft-js/issues/224) from Draft.js repository, I've found a static method called [moveSelectionToEnd](https://github.com/facebook/draft-js/blob/master/src/model/immutable/EditorState.js#L318). Everything that I need to do is wrap the brand new state with this method, this way.

```
  getEditorState() {
    const { reply: { channel, userAccount } } = this.props
    const content = this.getEditorContent({ channel, userAccount })
    const decorators = this.getEditorDecorators(channel)
    const state = EditorState.createWithContent(content, decorators)
    return EditorState.moveSelectionToEnd(state)
  }
```